# Multi-line URLs are not properly colored in floating captions

Tags: urls, amsart

With document class `amsart`, urls are not properly colored when spanning more than one line in figure captions and table captions.
I want them colored.
The `xurl` package is not relevant to the bug, but a solution should not contradict `xurl`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \caption{
            The last line is not properly colored
            \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/999999/The-last-line-is-not-properly-colored.}
        }
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{
            The last line is not properly colored
            \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/999999/The-last-line-is-not-properly-colored.}
        }
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try package `caption`, because it solves quite a few package incompatibilities.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Is this how you would order these packages? `caption` after `hyperref`?

Comment: The `caption` package needs to know, which other relevant packages are used. Therefore, I have loaded it *after* package `hyperref`. It it is loaded before `hyperref`, the caption package defers its code to `\begin{document} `.